# Can you use XMLHttpRequest to track large SQL update loop in code behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I allow end users to upload a file, then read into memory, and loop through it to update data. I am wondering a way i can report progress of the SQL loop i do in C# back to the UI just like we do for the file upload. We use ajax POST, then read by line, so when doing larger reads, i want a progress status of how many lines we have read. Is this possible, or does this only work with upload / download streams of files.

Here is the ajax call that does the file upload, and while waiting for the AJAX to return a response, the file progress works great for the file being upload but not the loop tracking.

```
 var form = $('#FormUpload')[0];
        var dataString = new FormData(form);

        $("#cboxClose").trigger("click");

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Uploader/Upload',  //Server script to process data
            type: 'POST',
            xhr: function () {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if (myXhr.upload) { // Check if upload property exists
                    //myXhr.upload.onprogress = progressHandlingFunction
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandlingFunction,
                        false); // For handling the progress of the upload
                }
                return myXhr;
            },
            //Ajax events
            success: uploadSuccessHandler,
            error: uploadErrorHandler,
            //complete: completeHandler,
            // Form data
            data: dataString,
            //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
    }
```

Here is part of the C# controller from MVC i call, but i have limited and made logic general for purposes of this question.

```
 try
        {
            if (uploadedFile != null && uploadedFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                if (uploadedFile != null)
                {
                    if (uploadedFile.ContentLength > 0)
                    {

                        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(uploadedFile.InputStream))
                        {
                            string currentLine;
                            int counterLine = 0;
                            // currentLine will be null when the StreamReader reaches the end of file
                            while ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                if (counterLine > 0)
                                {

                                    String fixedLine = currentLine;

                                    if (currentLine.Contains("/"))
                                    {
                                        fixedLine = currentLine.Remove('/');
                                    }

                                    string[] columns = fixedLine.Split(',');

                                    quoteDataRows.Add(new QuoteEntityItemVM()
                                    {
                                        Manufacturer = columns[0],
                                        Model = columns[2],
                                        Description = columns[1],
                                        LineID = lineCountId += 1

                                    });
                                }

                                counterLine += 1;
                            }
                        }
                   }
             }
```

Is there a way i can use modern AJAX to not only show progress of the uplaod, but while the counter loops report back progress to the UI something like ("Lines read (n) of total line (n)" back to the UI, or is this not possible?

-Thanks-

Comment: You could send request to your api to check how many lines has been read. Or you could configure a websocket https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/HTML-5-Web-Socket-e679d61d

Comment: How do i send request to API and report that back if it is in different call? could you provide basic example? This is probably straight forward and im over looking this.

Comment: Actually, i like the web-socket method, and forgot about it now in HTML5. Thanks and will try that out. Will post answer if i resolve it.

Comment: Im not sure how i would send back integer count to UI using the web socket example show. I see you construct with context, but how do i feed to the "Message" event in my c# loop to write back to the socket?

Comment: Unfortunately, c# is out of my scope, in java, you would call an object from the current session to pass the message, it should be similar in c#. You should take a look at the official documentation.